# Problems spawning draggable objects from database using web2py and jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, web2py

I am attempting to build a small proof-of-concept web application using the web2py framework. I'm so close, but my basic lack of knowledge of what's going on means I'm just hacking at it with pure guesswork rather than understanding what's going on. I was hoping someone on here could explain where I am going wrong...

The functionality I'm after is that the data needed to create the draggable items is held in a database table (and will ultimately form a hierarchy) with as little information held in the HTML as possible.

There's a fair bit of information for just about everything in this stack, so much so that I'm drowning in it, I don't know where to start. I suppose I should begin with what I've got so far...

The HTML:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: 'dragndrop.py',
      success: function( response ) {
        $("#draggable7").html(response);
      }
     } )
});
</script>

<div id="draggable7"></div>
```

The dragndrop.py script:

```
## My main draggable spawner
selected = [row.id for row in db(db.t_user_shop_layouts.id==7).select()]
return ''.join([DIV('draggable'.join(k), _class='draggable ui-widget-content', _snap=".ui-widget-header", _snapMode= "inner", _grid= [ 80, 80 ], _style='position: relative;') for k in selected])
```

And, just for completeness, the model web2py script (although the column I'm interested in is the "id" column, which is auto-generated):

```
db.define_table('t_shop_layout_items',
    Field('f_item_display_name_string', type='string', notnull=True,
          label=T('Item Display Name String')),
    Field('f_item_icon_file', type='upload',
          label=T('Item Icon File')),
    Field('f_item_parent_id', type='integer',
          label=T('Item Parent Id')),
    auth.signature,
    format='%(f_item_display_name_string)s',
    migrate=settings.migrate)
```

I'm forcing the db call to only pick up one row at the moment (id == 7) just to get the ball rolling, but eventually what I'd like to do is have the (db.id == db.f_item_parent_id) items shown first. Then when double-click, any (db.f_item_parent_id == this.id) children get spawned using helpers. Then I'm going to get an 80x80 grid size target to land on to set shop layout, and save to db. But all this paragraph is for later, I'm just giving you an idea of where I'm going with it.

Finally, some great tutorials that have helped me along the way, but were either not web2py (PHP seems popular for this) or not dynamically spawning (but hard-coded in the HTML, or what-have-you. If I've missed something obvious, please let me know:

An excellent fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/qLhke/25/ and its stack overflow beginnings [Jquery drag drop form hidden value inserting into php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826075/jquery-drag-drop-form-hidden-value-inserting-into-php-mysql)

The web2py documentation: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/34/11/jquery-and-ajax

OK, hope that's enough! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web2py, you do not create .py files and then use them as URLs. Instead, you create functions in controllers and have URLs of the form /appname/controller/function. See the documentation on [dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Dispatching). It is also best to use the built-in `URL()` function to generate URLs. Also, this should probably be a GET request rather than POST.

You might also want to look into web2py's built-in [`ajax()` function](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax#The-ajax-function) as well as [Ajax components](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12/components-and-plugins#Components--LOAD-and-Ajax).

Regarding your data model, if the `f_item_parent_id` field is a self reference, then you should define it as a reference field (i.e., `type='reference t_shop_layout_items'`).

More generally, before proceeding further, it will probably be very helpful if you read more of the documentation, particularly chapters [4](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core), [5](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer), [11](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax), and possibly [12](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12/components-and-plugins).

Comment: Many thanks, Anthony. I appreciate the time taken to help point me in the right direction. I'm learning a lot of new skills here (I'm mainly a database guy by trade) and I feel a bit embarrassed for asking, but this is all good advice.

Comment: Anthony, that's brilliant, thank you. I'm reading through the excerpts you suggested and already it is beginning to make more sense. The data model suggestion is spot on (although I need to back up my data and regenerate that table yet, it makes sense) as is the pointer to the URL() function. I'm marking this as answered as it exactly what I was after. I'll update my code as and when I get it working. Thanks again!